# Chart.js: Force display of a certain label with autoSkip: true

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

First of: Here's the code for a very simple chart I have created using Chart.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta lang="en">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="chart" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
        <script>

            var MiniChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d"), {
                type: "line",
                data: {
                    labels: ["Sept 18","Oct 18","Nov 18","Dec 18","Jan 19","Feb 19","Mar 19","Apr 19","May 19","Jun 19","Jul 19","Aug 19"],
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [1234,345,2341,14532,14331,12345,124,145,13425,14235,1214,0],
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(156, 210, 229, 0.2)"
                    }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: false,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                maxRotation: 0,
                                minRotation: 0,
                                autoSkipPadding: 10,
                                reverse: true
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                maxRotation: 0,
                                minRotation: 0
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                },
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The autoSkip function works perfectly by omitting multiple labels. However, it seems that Chart.js always displays the first label and skips the labels in intervals so the x-Axis gets labeled neatly.

In my case however, I'd like to have the *last* label displayed (in this case, "Aug 19") for certain. I tried to do this by reversing the array and also using the `reverse` option, but that didn't work. Is there any other way

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In `data: [...,14235,1214,]` last point missing. Should be `data: [...,14235,1214,0]`

Comment: @User863 Of course, you're right. Just fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This feature was removed by [this pull request](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5891), as you can see it is not possible to configure your chart to do the old behavior but you can write your own logic to render the ticks using the `afterBuildTicks` callback.

example:

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    afterBuildTicks: function (axis, ticks) {

    // max possible ticks
    const totElements = 20;

    if (ticks.length <= totElements) {
        return ticks;
    }
                            
    // this number is used to display a tick every n ticks
    const density = Math.trunc(ticks.length / totElements);

    if(isNaN(density)){
        console.warn('Nan in ticks')
        return ticks;
    }

    return ticks.filter((t, index) => {
        // always show the first and the last tick
        if (index === 0 || index === ticks.length - 1) {
            return t;
        } else if (index % density === 0) {
            return t;
        }
    })
},...
```